# Hilbert polynomials on a scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

For a scheme $X$ of finite type over $k$, and a coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$, the Hilbert polynomial of $\mathcal{F}$ is defined by $\Phi(n)=\chi(\mathcal{F}(n))$.

And for a scheme $X$ over $S$ (with some suitable conditions), I was told that we can define Hilbert polynomials by defining on each fibers. That is, for each point $s\in S$, we consdier the Hibert polynomial $\Phi_s$ of the restriction $\mathcal{F}_s$ of the sheaf on the fiber $X_s$.

But I don't understand why can we define the Hilbert polynomials of $\mathcal{F}_s$?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  When discussing Hilbert polynomials it is usually understood that $X$ is projective with very ample line bundle $\mathcal O(1)$.  In the relative setting, you would need a projective $X/S$ with a very ample line bundle $\mathcal O(1)$ on $X$ relative to $S$.  This restricts to a very ample line bundle on each fiber, and you define the Hilbert polynomial in terms of the restricted line bundle.

Comment: Regarding your flag, I am somewhat hesitant to delete this question, because the answer is rather informative.  You are welcome to edit your question to make it clear exactly how you were confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seconding Jack, it is not clear what question you are asking.  However, my guess is that you want to know why, or rather when, the Hilbert polynomial is well-defined independently of the geometric point $s$ of $S$.  With the hypotheses that Jack listed, if you also assume that $\mathcal{F}$ is an $S$-flat, locally finitely presented, quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module, then the Hilbert polynomial functions, $s\mapsto \chi(X_s,\mathcal{F}_s(n))$, is a locally constant function from $S$ to the Abelian group of numerical $\mathbb{Q}$-modules.  One reference for this is the corollary on p. 50 of Mumford's "Lectures on curves on an algebraic surface".